# Calculate and Restart Sequential ID for Unique Values in a Field

Tags: arcpy, cursor, count

I need to calculate a sequential ID for unique values in a field. So, for the values in Field1, the sequential ID count should count all occurrences of that value, then restart the count for the next value. For the example below, column 1 contains the values to count, column 2 is what the sequential field result should look like.

A             1

A             2

B             1

B             2

B             3

B             4

C             1

D             1

D             2

D             3

My plan was to approach this with an update cursor and the classic autoIncrement code, but it calculated all rows in the table with a sequential ID. I know the if/else is the wrong approach, but I was hoping the autoIncrement would start over within each if statement. I'm guessing I need to get a count of the unique values in Field1, then somehow calculate the sequential ID on the row as it counts? I saw a collections.Counter example, but wasn't sure if that could be applied here.

```
table = table path
fields = ('FIELD1,FIELD2')

rec=0
def autoIncrement():
    global rec
    pStart = 1
    pInterval = 1 
    if (rec == 0): 
        rec = pStart 
    else: 
        rec = rec + pInterval 
        return rec

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, fields) as uc:
    for row in uc:
        if row[0] == 'A':
            row[1] = str(autoIncrement())
        etc.
```

Comment: Can be done using field calculator. Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156140/can-labels-for-overlapping-points-be-combined-merged-into-one-label/156183#156183 All you need is replace return 2 line with return len (...)

Comment: The indentation for your autoIncrement, as presented in the question, is incorrect.  Please make sure that any code snippets presented work up to where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import arcpy

id_field = 'ID_Field'
calc_field = 'Calc_Field'
fc = r'C:\TEMP\points.shp'

values = []
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, [id_field, calc_field]) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        values.append(row[0])
        row[1] = '{}{}'.format(row[0], values.count(row[0]))
        rows.updateRow(row)

print 'done'
```

Comment: When I tried this the following error occurred: "...The value type is incompatible with the field type. [Calc_Field]".  Based on that msg I tried it with Calc_Field as a string type field.  No errors resulted, but the string output was a concatenation of ID_Field and the incremental number.  So it would work IF the output was numeric and the ID_Field was dropped.  I don't know Python that well, so I don't know how to fix it.  Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you want that classic auto-increment function to use.For me it is working fine-just change the variables.

```
import arcpy


#Set all needed variables
fc = r'C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\knp_office'
flds = ['Type','flg']
inc_fld = 'flg' # field where consecutive numbers are placed--field type is text
category_fld = 'Type' # field based on which serial/autoincrement is calculated--field type is text
vals = []


rec=0
def autoIncrement():
    global rec
    pStart = 1
    pInterval = 1 
    if (rec == 0): 
        rec = pStart 
    else: 
        rec+= pInterval 
    return rec



curU = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,flds)
for row in curU:
    vals.append(row[0])
del curU
vals=set(vals)



for i in vals:
    curU=arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,flds,category_fld+" = '%s'"%i)
    for row in curU:
        print "rec: "+str(rec)
        row[1] = i+" "+str(autoIncrement())
        curU.updateRow(row)
    del curU
    rec=0
```

Comment: This code will not be very efficient if there are a lot of unique values as you are creating a new cursor for each one.