# Single label for multiple features with different values in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, labeling, python-parser

I have several sample locations, that have been sampled several times at the same location. I want to label each location with stacked data from each location. So it would hopefully look like this

"Sample Location 1:

Depth 0-6: .314

Depth 6-12: .315

Depth 12-48: .398"

And so on. The problem right now, is that if I try and label them with label expressions, I can stack the fields but not the rows. So I get 5 labels for each location. This is because the depth measurements have their own points. I need the unique values so I cannot dissolve/aggregate the points into mean values, so that eliminates a lot of tools.

I also cannot simply display the different readings in labels located around the point. Because there are so many points, and I need to label all of them, the only way I can think of to label all of them at once is to combine them into single labels for each point and THEN do Maplex operations to get all the labels displayed properly.

I have explored python expressions and I am having a hard time finding something close to what I am doing. This StackOverFlow question has been suggested for me to attempt but it has not worked for me:
[Can labels for overlapping points be combined/merged into one label?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156140/can-labels-for-overlapping-points-be-combined-merged-into-one-label/156183#156183)

When I try the "Update #2" code in that solution it simply says "No Features Found: Could not Verify Expression". I am also not sure that's what I am even looking for because I do not want the sample data averaged or aggregated; I want the unique sample data displayed for each point.

In terms of label expression, I think of pseudocode like this:

```
def FindLabel ( [SAMPLE], [DEPTH], [READING]): 
     print [SAMPLEID]
     for [DEPTH] within [SAMPLEID]:
        return [DEPTH],  [GLNPO_TOTA], [FIELDS_TOT]
```

Where hopefully it would be possible to have ArcGIS display a sample location, then the depths and values below it, all as one label. That's the idea at least.

Comment: I think the [second half of this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/156183/115) to the duplicate indicated on [your earlier question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164533/label-expressions-with-python-question-multiple-rows-in-single-label) does the hard part of what you seem to be trying to do.  What happened when you tried it?  Formatting the text is easy, the hard part is aggregating the points and their data to make the labelling easy.

Comment: I cannot aggregate the data because the unique values have to be maintained. 

In that example answer I don;t understand what "MUID" would correspond to in my attribute table. I tried substituting the sample location, and the sample IDs, and that didn't work. Whether it is MUID or sample locations in both cases it says "No features Found"

Comment: You would aggregate only for labelling purposes and still maintain your original data.  I've not tried the solution but if this was my question I would [edit] it to say something like "when I did these exact steps to try the solution suggested at ... this is precisely what happened on a simple test case of 3 points at the same location".

Comment: But I don't want to aggregate for labeling purposes either. I need unique values listed for each point and labelled. I can't average the depths of each location because I want to label and show the values at each depth. Unless I am not understanding what you mean by aggregating points.

Comment: Aggregating in this case means adding extra fields and using a cursor to transfer values. If three points have a field with one value, and you know three is the maximum number of points at a location, use three fields to store the three values on one point.

Answer (score 1):

Look at my code in [this blog post](https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2015/02/07/creating-labels-with-related-table-data) for how to connect a single point to a separate table or feature class to list all of the related data stored in multiple records/points.  You want to dissolve your points based on a location ID to create a separate point feature class that contains just a single point for each physical location (you won't be using any aggregated fields created by the dissolve, just the location ID).  This avoids having to deal with label duplication and greatly improves the speed of labeling.  The single point feature class must have a field with a unique ID for each point that is also contained in all of the overlapping points at that location.  Then the code can list all of the overlapping point data in a single label using a cursor and a dictionary.

The key to the code I have designed is the use of a global dictionary variable in the label expression that is populated for all points once by a cursor when the first label is being created.  The actual labels do not read the data directly from the cursor, they just use the dictionary, which is at least 10 times faster than running separate queries for each point.  The dictionary key is the Unique ID for each unique physical point location and the value associated with each dictionary key contains a list of all the related data you need from the separate points for each given location.  Once you are set up to read field data from the lists in the dictionary, the rest of the label code is all about formatting the output.

Comment: having some trouble getting this working, here's what I've tried:

1: I dissolved based on the locations and did them as singlepart. So the dissolve table only has the sample location in it.

2: Then I related that dissolve table to the original table, based on the sampleID.

3: I then changed the code from the blog so it is pointing to my dissolve table for the relate, the labelkey is the sample ID, but for "relatefield list" I only put SampleID. If I try to put other fields it says column not found.


4: Line 49 in example 1 isn't working for me; it says Tuple out of range when run (cont.)

Comment: "expression += '\n{} - {:.4f}'.format(fieldValues[1], fieldValues[0])  " causes "Tuple out of range". I tried changing it to the field names of the columns I want to display (so it is expression += '\n' + [DEPTH] + [TOTAL] on line 49) but that causes issue where it says "findlabel not defined". 

Am I supposed to include the fields I want displayed in label in the relate table?

Comment: I'm marking what you said as answered because even though I'm having issues getting this working for me it's clear that with some tweaks this is what I needed

Comment: The code in example 1 should be modified in 4 lines.  Line 3 should be modified to def FindLabel ( [SAMPLEID] ):  Line 9 should change to your related points/table path (it must contain the SAMPLEID, DEPTH, and TOTAL fields).  Line 12 should be changes to: relateFieldsList = ["SAMPLEID", "DEPTH", "TOTAL"]  Line 34 should change to: labelKey = [SAMPLEID]   Line 49 should not be changed if you made these 4 other changes.

Comment: In sample 1 you would also want to make the label text fit your data better by changing the string from "Cross Street Count = " in line 43 and line 53 to "Sample Count = ".

Comment: I get the error on line 49, "ValueError: Unknown Formatcode 'f' for object of type 'str'. I did a little searching and the fix was not clear. I tried to change line 49 to be:

'       expression += '\n{} - {:.4f}'.format(float(fieldValues[1], fieldValues[0])) '

but that will not work because float only takes one argument

Comment: Tried changing the fields in the dissolve table to string instead of double, but it still gave me an error. Unfortunately the fields in the original table are double type, if that is what is causing the issue

Comment: Yes, that could cause an error, since the label I constructed expected one numeric field and one string field and used python numeric formatting syntax in line 49.  To eliminate the formatting error, change {:.4f} in Line 49 to just {}, i.e.:   expression += '\n{} - {}'.format(fieldValues[1], fieldValues[0])  Make sure no values are Null in the table.

Comment: Just to be sure, I have verified that the code in the Blog still works with the original data that I designed it for.  So the code in the Blog is sound.  Hopefully the only errors left are just dealing with label formatting issues.  Once you get the Example 1 code to work you will be focused on learning more about how to tweak the formatting in Python anyway to get a label design that works best for your particular data.

Comment: I got it working! Thanks so much, you're a life saver. I have no idea how I would have gotten this working without your help.

Comment: I am glad to hear that.  I expect you noticed that the Depth field values were in the Right column and the Total field values were in the Left column.  I am sure you want to swap that.  To change the column order in the label modify line 49 to reverse the field order, i.e.:  expression += '\n{} - {}'.format(fieldValues[0], fieldValues[1])

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did. I also added another expression+= to add a totally different column and it worked great too without causing issues.

Comment: When you get it as pretty as you want it, I would be interested in seeing a screenshot of what you came up with.  Please add a note to your original post that shows the final result.  That should help others understand how the code resolved your problem.

Comment: I'll do that for sure, thanks again for the help. We do this sort of thing a lot so this technique will come in handy in the future, too