# ArcGIS combine labels/annotations by feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am trying to find a way to combine multiple data points into one based on the same latitude longitude in a dataset. Basically too many labels appear for one point.

**Example data**

```
Name     Latitude     Longitude     Time
John     12.34567     -12.34567     10:42 AM
Marley   98.76543     -98.76543     11:52 AM
Alex     98.76543     -98.76543     12:00 PM
Heather  12.34567     -12.34567     9:16 AM
Angie    12.34567     -12.34567     5:47 PM
```

I am trying to combine this is a way so that the time labels will appear as one for the same latitude and longitude points. Is there an easy automated way to accomplish this?

**Example output**

```
Name                        Latitude     Longitude     Time
John \n Heather \n Angie     12.34567     -12.34567    10:42 AM \n 9:16 AM \n 5:47 PM
Marley \n Alex               98.76543     -98.76543    11:52 AM \n 12:00 PM
```

It does not need to be in the above format with newlines. Just trying to think of ways to do this.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156140/can-labels-for-overlapping-points-be-combined-merged-into-one-label/156183#156183

Comment: Thank you Felix. I am trying the bottom function from the Nov 2016 update. I have placed the expression in my label expression but I am receiving an error message that FindLabel is not defined. Also what will I need to label my latlong fields for this to work? Thank you for your help!

Comment: No need in xy field.Tested on point shapefiles, label stored in field "muid". Layer is the 1st in table of content.