# Combining labels for multiple points in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser, vbscript

I have a data set that has stacked points. I need to display the labels as one. I've seen this solution [Can labels for overlapping points be combined/merged into one label?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156140/can-labels-for-overlapping-points-be-combined-merged-into-one-label) but it only works for a single field expression where as I'm trying to label multiple fields. Anyone have any ideas?

First Image is what I currently have using VBScript and Maplex on ArcMap 10.7.

[image: Current Label using vbscript]

The second image is what I would like to get to.

[image: Desired Label]

the VBScript I'm using is:

```
"<BOL>" & [LocationID] & "</BOL>" & vbnewline & "<UND>" & [MediumSub] & "</UND>" & vbnewline & "n = " & [n] & vbnewline & [GeoMean]
```

[image: VBScript Label]

Any wizards out there that have any good ideas?

Comment: Just combine fields into single one?

Comment: 3 fields need to be repeated in the label for each point. MediumSub, n, and GeoMean.  The LocationID only needs to be displayed once.

Comment: So, you have 2 points max that overlap?

Comment: 2-3 is the norm but it's possible there could be 5 or more.